# Mouse scroll Up (Ncurses / C++)

Tags: c++, ncurses

My problem is I can't figure how to scroll down and up using ncurses5 and mouse event.

I know this is a feature of ncurses5.6+ but there I'm not able to know if I can get this version from packagers or not.

Even if I can get it, zsh, bash, sh and so on can scroll well on each terminal (how ?), is this hardware feature ? Can I get my own in my c++ program without adding more lib than ncurses, c stantard and std ?

This code works well for scroll down but don't compile when I try to integrate BUTTON5_PRESSED (because of my ncurses version).

So on, actually I could handle down scroll but not the up scroll. Is there a way to handle the both ?

```
 // mouse event structure
  MEVENT event;

  if (getmouse(&event) == OK) {
    printw("mouse Event OK");
    if (event.bstate & BUTTON4_PRESSED)
      wprintw(_win, "Button4\n");
    else if (event.bstate & BUTTON5_PRESSED) // does not compile
      wprintw(_win, "Button5\n");
  }
```

my actual code is hosted on github https://github.com/Liroo/Nanotekspice/blob/master/lib/cli/mode/NcursesMode.cpp, check it out if you get motivated! (btw, use it with this command to get ncurses format: `./nanotekspice resources/basics/test.nts c=1 --mode=ncurses`)

Comment: Don't spam tags. C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: This behavior can be coded in c as well as c++... I thought that I could use both tags

Comment: Sure, I will not reproduce this error.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite you are not right in this case. The code is valid for both C and C++, and most importantly, the same included library is applicable to both languages. It's perfectly valid to use both tags in this case. Also, despite it's a `.cpp` example file, I would suspect that more C users would be familiar with ncurses

Answer (score 1):

short: no, there's no workaround

long —
The wheel mouse (by convention) sends button-4 and button-5 for up/down events.  ncurses**5** does not provide encoding for both of these buttons.  That is an extension (from [September 2005](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20050917)) which is standard with ncurses**6** ([August 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html#h2-release-notes)):

> These notes are for ncurses 6.0, released August 8, 2015.
>
> This release is designed to be source-compatible with ncurses 5.0 through 5.9; providing a new application binary interface (ABI). Although the source can still be configured to support the ncurses 5 ABI, the intent of the release is to provide extensions which are generally useful, but binary-incompatible with ncurses 5:
>
> - Extend the cchar_t structure to allow more than 16 colors to be encoded.
> - Modify the encoding of mouse state to make room for a **5th mouse button**. That allows one to use ncurses with a wheel mouse with xterm or similar X terminal emulators.

Further reading:

- [Symbol-versioning in ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-mapsyms.html)

Comment: Thanks for information, and do you know if there is ncurses package on apt-get / zypper which support this feature ?

Comment: Anything that says "ncurses6" or 'ncurses-6.0" in the package name.  Debian's been doing this in testing for about a year.  I'm not sure of OpenSUSE...